# Booting to windows safe mode with dual boot ubuntu not working

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

So I haven't used windows in a little while and when I tried to today, I am getting the error "user cannot be loaded." One of the advised solutions is to boot in safe mode, but apparently I can't.

I am running an SSD so everything goes by in a second. I've tried spamming f8 once I choose enter, also spamming f8, esc, f8... Nothing seems to work?

Comment: How about unplugging PC power when u r running windows. The next time you select windows it will ask for option to run in safe mode - since the shutdown did not happen normally. This is not the right solution though... But good enough to get you in safe mode (A TWEAK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like either the user registry or folder is corrupt.
Try using chntpw from ubuntu to re-enable windows built in administrator account and clear its password then log in with that account.